# how I use webContents.executeJavaScript execute a function that which be defined in preload.js

Tags: javascript, electron

/*
I want to call a function which defined in the preload.js file, but it getting an error.
Instead, I just execute an alert (" aaaaaa "), which does the job correctly
*/
main process:

```js
const winViewBrowser = new BrowserView({
backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
webPreferences: {
contextIsolation:true,
preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
}
});

win.setBrowserView(winViewBrowser);
winViewBrowser.webContents.loadURL(url_local);
winViewBrowser.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
winViewBrowser.webContents.executeJavaScript(aa();, true).then((result) => {
console.log(result);
})
});
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
renderer preload.js

```js
aa = () => {
alert(123123123);
}
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

but it does not work!
[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq70g.png)

Comment: Please paste the error messages into the post.

Comment: FYI you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

can use contextBridge to export api to mainprocess

> https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge